# Defining variables outside methods and getting their return value

Tags: java, sorting, methods

Exactly what the title says. I have to write a code that runs all three sorting methods (bubble, insertion, selection). So far I have the bubble part ready, but I don't know how to get it to work because you have to define a variable when you're declaring the method so that you can get a return value. But I need it to return the variables defined outside the method. Is there any possible way to do that? Keep in mind that I also need the same values used again in two more methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sorting {

static int d = 0;
static int c = 0;
static int n = 0;
static int swap = 0;
static int array[] = new int[n];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Number of elements: ");
    n = scan.nextInt();



    System.out.print("Enter " + n + " elements: ");

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) 
      array[c] = scan.nextInt();
}

    static void BubbleSort(int[] a) { //this line!!

    for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
      for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
        if (array[d] > array[d+1])
        {
          swap       = array[d];
          array[d]   = array[d+1];
          array[d+1] = swap;
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.print("Bubble sort: ");

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
      System.out.print(array[c] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: `"you have to define a variable when you're declaring the method so that you can get a return value"` -- well, no, you don't actually.  `"I need it to return the variables defined outside the method"` -- Your bubble sort method doesn't return anything right now, you have defined it as returning `void` (no return value) instead of a return type.

Comment: Another issue at a glance:  You define `array` as a size `0` array, so your program will crash on `array[c] = scan.nextInt();`.  You need to create your array *after* you get the size from the user, or put your input in a `List` and convert it to an array when calling your sort.

Comment: thank you for your input, i've learned a lot from my mistakes! i'm still a little unclear on the first part, but janos's code seems to be working fine so analyzing it might help me further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to understand what you're asking:

- The `BubbleSort` method takes an `int[] a` parameter but never uses it
- The `main` method reads numbers into an array but then never calls `BubbleSort`
- You're asking about the return value of `BubbleSort`, but the method is declared `void`, and it modifies the content of `array`, a `static` variable: it seems that this method is not intended to return anything, but sort an array in-place
- Many unused variables
- Many variables declared static in the class when they could be local variables in methods, some of them local inside `for` loops

With the above issues fixed,
your implementation would make a lot more sense like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n, c;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Number of elements: ");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[n];

        System.out.print("Enter " + n + " elements: ");

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            array[c] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        BubbleSort(array);
    }

    static void BubbleSort(int[] array) {

        int n = array.length;

        for (int c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
                if (array[d] > array[d + 1]) {
                    int swap = array[d];
                    array[d] = array[d + 1];
                    array[d + 1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Bubble sort: ");

        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            System.out.print(array[c] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, works much better than what i had, and plus i tried adding the insertion sort the same way and it worked! thank you, i've learned a great deal!

Comment: The array isn't copied so by this method you can only do one sort per execution.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your method add:

```
int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
```

NOTE: this is necessary in order for the array to be used two more times.

Now you have a new array and you can operate on `b` without affecting the array that was passed in for `a`. You can change your header to `static int[] BubbleSort(int[] a)` and at the end `return b;`.

Comment: This is very usefull answer, OP wants to compare the return values, so the array has to be copied +1

Answer (score -2):

A `void` method can't return a value. If you want `int[] a` to be passed to `BubbleSort()`, sorted, then returned, then the header should look like this:

```
static int[] BubbleSort(int[] a) {
```

The method also needs to end with a return statement:

```
return a;
```

Comment: If you sort the array in method, you dont need to return it, it will be sorted. It is because of you are passing a reference to array, not value @BethanyLouise

Comment: The array needs to be reused multiple times, but because arrays are references in java it will be changed after the first sort.